# Kubernetes install on ACS incomplete?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

I have tried three installs through the portal and finally one completely through Azure CLI (with Ubuntu on Windows).  Each time the deployment completes but remotely run commands because they fail with "resource temporarily unavailable". I can SSH into the master server. When I do I find the kubectl commands all come up empty (nodes, pods, namespace, version). Service --status-all does not list a single Kubernete service (I would expect to see the API service at least).

When creating through the portal I manually created the SPN and verified I could login to Azure with it.  During the CLI setup I let the install create the SPN.

I have tried restarting the master but nothing changes.

What am I missing? It is probably something easy but I am spinning my tires.

Comment: does your service principal have the right needed?

Comment: please refer to this link about service principal https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-kubernetes-service-principal

Comment: SPN is set up and works with az login.  It has the contributor permission assigned at the subscription level.

Comment: I used the PowerShell script in Azure documentation to create the SPN the first few times.  Just tried the CLI method and everything works.